# AttributeError: __enter__

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, orm, flask-sqlalchemy

I defined a table in python using sqlalchemy but when i try to create it this error appears

```
import os

from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from models import *

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = os.getenv("DATABASE_URL")
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
db.init_app(app)

def main():
    db.create_all()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with app.app_context().push:
        main()
```

Error :

> Traceback (most recent call last): file "create.py", line 15, in
>    with app.app_context().push(): AttributeError: __ enter __

Comment: The image of the error does not match the image of the code. Post exactly the code you are trying to run (not an image), exactly the command you are using to run it, and exactly the text returned as an error.

Comment: and to add on, the error in the image is not the one indicated in the title

Comment: Please read [why you should not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Sorry i'm editing the post now

Comment: did you try db initialization with, db = SQLAlchemy() and then db.init_app(app) ?

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from models import *

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = os.getenv("DATABASE_URL")
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
db.init_app(app)

def main():
    with app.app_context():
       db.create_all()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

That way, it should work.